# background image fixed at 50% right, part hidden under viewport and viewable when viewport is expanded

Tags: css, viewport

I am trying to show a large image on a website. The design specification is to show part of the image and the rest is hidden outside the viewport. As you drag the viewport/browser wider you will see more of the image.

This is the test site: http://kazoup.airboxmedia.com/

I want the image of the Mac to stay put (around 50px right of the text) and as you widen the browser to see more of the image the image will stay the same distance from the text.

At the moment its a background image of a DIV which is 100%. I have tried adding it as IMG HTML but as soon as I force it off the screen I get horizontal scroll bars and I do not want this. I have also tried using % % on the background but this doesn't seem to keep it in the same place.

So I want it to be fixed with from the text, no scroll bars and able to view more of the image as you widen the browser.

Any ideas? I have been stuck all afternoon.

Many thanks in advance.

Jack

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can play with. And you really should include the relevant code in your question

Comment: Thanks, I didn't include any code as I'm not sure it if it is CSS or HTML? I'll work on a fiddle shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `img` instead of a `background-image`. Place the `img` inside of the `#wrapper` and then apply the CSS as below.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img class="hero-img" src="static/img/macbook.png">
    <!-- etc. -->
```

**CSS:**

```
#outerWrap2 {
    min-width: 940px; /* 940px is used because it is the width of #wrapper */
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.hero-img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 42%;
    top: 135px;
}
```

Obviously you can apply the css to the `img` with whatever class/id you like etc and modify the figures so that the image lines up exactly where you want it.

Comment: Thank you, that has worked perfectly. I have updated the link which you can see for yourself http://kazoup.airboxmedia.com/

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to accept the answer by marking/checking the tick under the arrows on the left.